# Can't extract text in Steganography

Tags: java, c#, android, steganography

i have a code to put a string value on a image using stenography in C# using code from here

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/635715/Steganography-Simple-Implementation-in-Csharp

now i have to extract the string on android side.
This is my android side code for text extraction

```
   private String extractText(Bitmap bmp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int colorUnitIndex = 0;
        int charValue = 0;

        // holds the text that will be extracted from the image
        String extractedText ="";

        for(int w=0;w<bmp.getHeight();w++)
        {
            for(int h=0;h<bmp.getWidth();h++)
            {
                int color=bmp.getPixel(h, w);
                green=Color.green(color);
                blue=Color.blue(color);
                red=Color.red(color);

                bred=(byte)red;
                bgreen=(byte)green;
                bblue=(byte)blue;

                // for each pixel, pass through its elements (RGB)
                for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                {
                    switch (colorUnitIndex % 3)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            {
                                // get the LSB from the pixel element (will be pixel.R % 2)
                                // then add one bit to the right of the current character
                                // this can be done by (charValue = charValue * 2)
                                // replace the added bit (which value is by default 0) with
                                // the LSB of the pixel element, simply by addition
                                charValue = charValue * 2 + bred % 2;
                            } break;
                        case 1:
                            {
                                charValue = charValue * 2 + bgreen % 2;
                            } break;
                        case 2:
                            {
                                charValue = charValue * 2 + bblue % 2;
                            } break;
                    }

                    colorUnitIndex++;

                    // if 8 bits has been added, then add the current character to the result text
                    if (colorUnitIndex % 8 == 0)
                    {
                        // reverse? of course, since each time the process happens on the right (for simplicity)
                        charValue = reverseBits(charValue);

                        // can only be 0 if it is the stop character (the 8 zeros)
                        if (charValue == 0)
                        {
                            return extractedText;
                        }

                        // convert the character value from int to char
                        char c = (char)charValue;

                        // add the current character to the result text
                        extractedText += String.valueOf(c);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return extractedText;


    }

    private int reverseBits(int n) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         int result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                result = result * 2 + n % 2;

                n /= 2;
            }

            return result;
    }

};
```

but I am not getting the correct string on android side.
Don't know whats the problem.
Can any one help??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the image is correctly transferred to the device? Are you sure that there are no endianness issues in the Bitmap format(check the values of few Pixels on the .NET side before sending, and check the same pixels on the Java side of the system)?

Comment: Also add the Java tag to your question, because it is partially code-conversion issue.

Comment: yes I am sure that image is correctly transferring to the android device.

Comment: And all colors are extracted correctly?

Comment: Also I have some reservations about the 'if 8 bits have been added' when 16 bits are actually needed for UTF-16 encoding. And multiplication by 2 in place of bitshifts. But the problem is that it is the same thing in the source example. I just want to tell you that that codeproject steganography example has more steganography in code than in the algorithm. It needs some cleaning and refactoring.

Comment: Try to: 1) Create two desktop apps that extract the text - one in C#(from CodeProject), another one in Java from your android code  2) Create an image with hidden text. 3) Launch and debug in parallel those two apps while they extract first byte(8 bits) or few from the image(just open it with FileShare.Read) 4) If they operate in the same way - then your problem is in the transition of data(or android peculiarities) 5) Otherwise it will be easy to see where the code conversion from C# to Java misinterpreted some construct or method.

Comment: OK.I will do it.Thanks

Comment: Hi, can someone share the complete code for encode and decode? I'm having difficulty translating the example code from C# to Android Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found the solution
simply by using this code on a loop for each bit I am able to extract the text.

```
               result[b] = (byte)((result[b] << 1) | (buff[offset] & 1));
```

Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have unsigned bytes (like c#).

```
int x = 176;
byte y = (byte)x; // if you print y, the result is: -80.
```

So in your code , whenever the RGB values greater than 127, it is interpreted as different value (-80 instead 176).

That code only checks the value of the rightmost bit, with module 2, which ofcourse can be carried out on int. So you can work directly with the "green", "blue" and "red" (remove "bgreen", "bblue" ,"bred"):

```
private static String extractText(BufferedImage bmp) 
{
    int colorUnitIndex = 0;
    int charValue = 0;

    String extractedText ="";

    for(int i=0;i<bmp.getHeight();i++)
    {
      for(int j=0;j<bmp.getWidth();j++)
      {
        Color color = new Color(bmp.getRGB(j, i));

        int green=color.getGreen();
        int blue=color.getBlue();
        int red=color.getRed();

        // for each pixel, pass through its elements (RGB)
        for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
        {
          switch (colorUnitIndex % 3)
          {
            case 0:
            {
              // get the LSB from the pixel element (will be pixel.R % 2)
              // then add one bit to the right of the current character
              // this can be done by (charValue = charValue * 2)
              // replace the added bit (which value is by default 0) with
              // the LSB of the pixel element, simply by addition
              charValue = charValue * 2 + red % 2;
            } break;
            case 1:
            {
              charValue = charValue * 2 + green % 2;
            } break;
            case 2:
            {
              charValue = charValue * 2 + blue % 2;
            } break;
          }

          colorUnitIndex++;

          // if 8 bits has been added, then add the current character to the result text
          if (colorUnitIndex % 8 == 0)
          {
            // reverse? of course, since each time the process happens on the right (for simplicity)
            charValue = reverseBits(charValue);

            // can only be 0 if it is the stop character (the 8 zeros)
            if (charValue == 0)
            {
              return extractedText;
            }

            // convert the character value from int to char
            char c = (char)charValue;

            // add the current character to the result text
            extractedText += String.valueOf(c);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return extractedText;
  }
```